# Using Tkinter to create rectangles for each cell of a 2d array

Tags: python, tkinter

I've created a 2d array like this:

```
a, b = 150, 150;
density = .5

def RedOrGreen():
  c = random.uniform(0,1)
  if c > density:
    d = "GREEN"
  else:
    d = "RED"
  return d

Matrix = [[RedOrGreen() for x in range(a)] for y in range(b)]
```

I'd like to use tkinter to create a square that has a lot of squares inside of it. These squares are represented by my 2d array. I want to make them either green or red, depending on the value in the 2d array. I tried to accomplish this by iterating through my 2d array, and creating rectangles like this:

```
        self.forest = tk.Canvas(self, width = 500, height = 500)
        for x in range(a):
            for y in range(b):
                self.forest.create_rectangle(x,y,x+1,y+1, fill = Matrix[x][y])
        self.forest.pack()
```

I've omitted some code for simplicity, but you can view the entire code here:
https://repl.it/repls/WindingUnwelcomeLibrary

However, this solution does not work. I'm not sure why it's not working, because in my head I am iterating through the 2d array, and then creating a corresponding rectangle. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Edit:
The reason it does not work is because it just displays a black canvas. It's not correctly populating the rectangles with the colors I want. I am not running it on repl.it, I just have it there to display the full code.

Comment: what means "doesn't work" ? Do you get error ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: `tkinter` on `repl.it` will not work. `tkinter` need access to real monitor but web servers mostly don't have monitors - and nobody couldn't see monitor connected to server (except server's admin)

Comment: @furas Editted with more information.

Comment: Please don't link to code on another site. That site may go away, or that code may go away, rendering this question useless. Instead, create a [mcve] specifically for this question.

Comment: What have you done to debug this? For example, instead of creating rectangles have you printed out the coordinates to make sure that they are correct? Have you printed out the color to make sure it is correct? How do you know you aren't a) creating rectangles off screen, or b) creating a bunch of black rectangles with no gaps between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `rectangle` has black border which hides other rectangles. And finally you have only black canvas.

You have to remove border using `width=0`

```
 self.forest.create_rectangle(x, y, x+1, y+1, fill=Matrix[x][y], width=0)
```

Doc: [Canvas](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm)

[image]